# Arduino P10 display and Time count

Tags: timer, arduino, dot-matrix

everyone, I am using, `P10 Dot Matrix Display` with `Arduino Uno`. I am using P10 Library from this link. [P10_LED](http://www.electroons.com/blog/ledp10-arduino-library-for-p10-led-display-panels/) and I need to display the one-hour countdown on the display module. The given library uses [TimerOne](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/timer-one) library. So for countdown i am using [MsTimer2](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/ms-timer2) library which usese timer2 of arduino.

When I individually run both of the libraries, my scrolling on the display is perfect and my timer library also generates a pure 1sec interrupt. Now what I did is the added both the library in my project and I am doing the countdown. But now suddenly my `MsTimer2` doesn't generate pure 1sec.

Here is the code.

```
#include <MsTimer2.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include"SPI.h"
#include <ledP10.h>

LedP10 myled;
uint8_t minute = 0, second = 0, hour = 1;
volatile bool xIsCountDone = false;
volatile bool xIsInterruptOcuured = false;
char time_buff[100];

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    myled.init(3,4,8,9 ,3);
    sprintf((char*)time_buff, "    %d%d:%d%d:%d%d", (hour/10), (hour%10),(minute/10), (minute%10),(second/10), (second%10));
    Serial.println((char*)time_buff);
    myled.showmsg_single_static((char*)time_buff, 0);
    xIsInterruptOcuured = false;
    //myled.showmsg_single_scroll("this is single led test",2,8,0);
    MsTimer2::set(1000, count);
    MsTimer2::start();
}

void loop() {
  if (xIsInterruptOcuured == true)
  {
    sprintf((char*)time_buff, "    %d%d:%d%d:%d%d", (hour/10), (hour%10),(minute/10), (minute%10),(second/10), (second%10));
    Serial.println((char*)time_buff);
    myled.showmsg_single_static((char*)time_buff, 0);
    xIsInterruptOcuured = false;
  }
}

void count(){
  second--;
  if (second <= 0 || second > 59)
  {
    second = 59;
    minute--;
    if (minute <= 0 || minute > 59)
    {
      minute = 59;
      hour--;
      if (hour <= 0 || hour > 12)
      {
        xIsCountDone =true;
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println(millis());
  xIsInterruptOcuured = true;
}
```

In the interrupt routine, I am printing `millis()` to see at after how many ms the interrupt occurs. The results are something like this.

> > 15:33:02.684 -> 1199
> >     15:33:04.371 -> 2396
> >     15:33:06.059 -> 3592
> >     15:33:07.746 -> 4783
> >     15:33:09.434 -> 5986
> >     15:33:11.121 -> 7181
> >     15:33:12.855 -> 8379
> >     15:33:14.543 -> 9578
> >     15:33:16.230 -> 10768
> >     15:33:17.918 -> 11974
> >     15:33:19.605 -> 13168
> >     15:33:21.292 -> 14365
> >     15:33:22.980 -> 15562
> >     15:33:24.667 -> 16751
> >     15:33:26.402 -> 17955

When I use only `MsTimer2` library the results are something like this.

> > 15:37:21.241 -> 998
> >     15:37:22.226 -> 1998
> >     15:37:23.257 -> 2998
> >     15:37:24.241 -> 3998
> >     15:37:25.226 -> 4998
> >     15:37:26.257 -> 5998
> >     15:37:27.241 -> 6998
> >     15:37:28.225 -> 7998
> >     15:37:29.257 -> 8998
> >     15:37:30.241 -> 9998
> >     15:37:31.225 -> 10998
> >     15:37:32.256 -> 11998
> >     15:37:33.241 -> 12998
> >     15:37:34.225 -> 13998
> >     15:37:35.256 -> 14998

My guess, it's happening because of the `TimerOne` library but I couldn't find the solution. In `ledP10.cpp` there is a callback method for `timer1` and it contains loops and may line of code. But is timer1 interrupts priority is higher than timer2? But according to the ATmega328p datasheet, the vector no. for Timer2 is less than Timer1. Doesn't that mean Timer2 has a higher priority? My ultimate goal is to do the one-hour countdown. Any help with this problem or any additional information i am missing which will be useful or any other solution other than using timer2 interrupt will be appreciated.

Regards.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I used with millis() and gave me around 12min difference.

```
uint8_t new_buff[100];
unsigned long startMillis;  //some global variables available anywhere in the program
unsigned long currentMillis;
const unsigned long period = 1000;  //the value is a number of milliseconds
uint8_t minute = 0, second = 0, hour = 1;
char time_buff[100];
void setup() 
{
    myled.init(3,4,8,9,3);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    sprintf((char*)time_buff, "    %d%d:%d%d:%d%d", (hour/10), (hour%10),(minute/10), (minute%10),(second/10), (second%10));
    //Serial.println((char*)time_buff);
    myled.showmsg_single_static((char*)time_buff, 0);
    startMillis = millis();
}



void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis();  //get the current "time" (actually the number of milliseconds since the program started)
  if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period)  //test whether the period has elapsed
  {
    Serial.println(millis());
    second--;
    startMillis = currentMillis;  //IMPORTANT to save the start time of the current LED state.
    if (second <=0 || second > 59)  {
      second = 59;
      minute--;
      if (minute <=0 || minute > 59)  {
        minute = 59;
        hour--;
        if (hour <= 0 || hour > 12) {
          hour = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    sprintf((char*)time_buff, "    %d%d:%d%d:%d%d", (hour/10), (hour%10),(minute/10), (minute%10),(second/10), (second%10));
    myled.showmsg_single_static((char*)time_buff, 0);
    startMillis = currentMillis;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to dig into your code atm. my lazy programmer's advice: get a realtime clock so you don't have to bother with timer interrupts :)

Comment: Even simpler solution would be to work with the `millis()` function, since the real time is not necessary for an one hour countdown.

Comment: @Fitzi using millis() also doesn't give accurate countdown. There is a huge difference around 12 min. I measured using the stopwatch.

Comment: @Piglet Yeah i have a spare ds3231 but i wanted to try it using timers. But if nothing happens that will be my only option

Comment: Can you show an example how you used millis? Because being 12 minutes off in an one hour countdown is very likely the result from some other issue, not millis being inaccurate.

Comment: @Fitzi I have edited the post and added the example with millis()

Comment: I see the problem, you keep adding one second to the current millis, so you accumulate many small errors. Try keeping track of the next second with a global variable `unsigned long nextMillis = 1000;` and in your loop always add `1000` to nextMillis once triggered: `if( millis() >= nextMillis ){ /* do your clock update here, nextMillis is your current time */ nextMillis += 1000; }` This will also result in some seconds beeing a few milliseconds longer or shorter than others, but you don't accumulate the errors. Also, you won't notice a few milliseconds with a resolution of one second.

Answer (score 1):

This answer targets your example using `millis()`. You can avoid accumulating errors over time, by not setting the next update relative to the current time. Rather just increment it by one second each time. This way, it does not matter if your main loop gets blocked by an interrupt for some milliseconds.

Also note that you don't have to save hours, minutes and seconds separately, you can just calculate them:

```
unsigned long nextMillis = 1000;
unsigned long targetTime = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour in milliseconds

void setup(){
    myled.init(3,4,8,9,3);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    updateMyLed(0);
}


void updateMyLed( unsigned long elapsedTime ){

    char buffer[100];       
    unsigned long timeLeftInSeconds = (targetTime - elapsedTime) / 1000;

    uint8_t hour = timeLeftInSeconds / 3600;
    timeLeftInSeconds -= hour * 3600;
    uint8_t minute = timeLeftInSeconds / 60;
    uint8_t second = timeLeftInSeconds - (minute * 60);

    sprintf((char*)buffer, "    %d%d:%d%d:%d%d", (hour/10), (hour%10), (minute/10), (minute%10), (second/10), (second%10));
    myled.showmsg_single_static((char*)buffer, 0);
}

void loop() {

    if( millis() >= nextMillis ){
        updateMyLed(nextMillis);
        nextMillis += 1000;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the logic you are using is good and i undeerstood it but to check if it gives the correct time i used just Serial.println(millis()) inside the if statement inside the loop and i found that there is to be exact 11.81 sec difference.

Comment: additionally i comment the ledp10 initialization and checked again and it gave me exact time.

Comment: now i think i should change the library for p10 display. all the problems are occuring from that library.

Comment: The p10 library very likely uses timers internally, which can mess things up. But if it really messes up the `millis()` function as well, then you should change it, yes.

Comment: are you familar with any library for the display module I am using? what are the chances that the library will not be messing with millis()? I better switch to ds3231 to fetch the time from rtc. what do you suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with these displays or librarys to control them. I would recommend checking the documentations for any timer or interrupt mentioned though.

Answer (score 0):

In the Arduino world, some libraries are disabling the interrupts.

This happens with all WS2812 LEDS and also yours. Without disabling interrupts, there would be a timing problem with the external devices.

So, you should never use interrupts or library with interrupts, if you use another one who will disable the interrupts.

Do you want use the P10 library? You can, but do not use interrupts in your code. Do not add other libraries like IR_remote, since it will not work correctly.

Back to your problem, just update your timer in the loop. And do not wait until the a second is over to update your time by 1 second! This will always be more than 1second.

You can for example convert the millis to seconds `seconds = millis() / 1000;`.
Your loop could be so:

```cpp
void loop() {
  currentSeconds = millis() / 1000;  //get the current "time" (actually the number of milliseconds since the program started)
  if (currentSeconds != savedSeconds)  //test whether the period has elapsed
  {
    savedSeconds = currentSeconds;
    Serial.println(millis());
    second--;
    if (second <=0 || second > 59)  {
      second = 59;
      minute--;
      if (minute <=0 || minute > 59)  {
        minute = 59;
        hour--;
        if (hour <= 0 || hour > 12) {
          hour = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    sprintf((char*)time_buff, "    %d%d:%d%d:%d%d", (hour/10), (hour%10),(minute/10), (minute%10),(second/10), (second%10));
    myled.showmsg_single_static((char*)time_buff, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the information. yes, I have to use p10 display and library for that but it can be any library for p10, not this library in particular as long as I can scroll and show strings. coming to the code I quite didn't understand the logic. you have used `currentSeconds = millis() / 1000;` then you have checked currentSeconds != savedSeconds. There will be many times my saved second will not be equal to current seconds and condition will be true most of the time and display will update many time

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated the code. You have to save the savedSeconds. The main problem with library who disable interrupts is that your interrupt will not be executes each time. And in the loop in your script you are just checking if the 1 second time is elapsed to decrease your time by 1. But this can be true also when 1.2 seconds are elapsed. Also in my case, this can happens once the time elapsed is more than 1 second, but you don't loose any milliseconds with this method.